# Bottom of text in select box is being cut off

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

[What the Text boxes look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhEPo.png)

Bottom of text in select box is being cut off. I am using class form-control and I believe that it is the padding that is cutting it off. I have tired changing the padding to 0 in the .css file to no avail. I have also looked for  select.form-control in the file and I do not have one. I tried to add one from another post with a similar problem however that did not work either. Please help this is really grinding my gears.

Code I am using:

```
  <select name="inputOverNightParking" id="inputOverNightParking" class="form-control">
    <option selected="OverNightParking">Over Night Parking</option>    
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: Set some larger `height` to the select boxes

Comment: We need a [mcve] please.